# Can quantum entanglement be a proof of a 4th spatial dimension?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, spacetime-dimensions

What I know about quantum entanglement is almost nothing. What I know can be resumed to: "two particles created together have a correlated behaviour no matter the distance between them".

This is often interpreted as a faster-than-light phenomenon because it is instantaneous.

But let's consider a 4th spatial dimension (we then have x,y,z,w)

- 2 particles are created in the point x=0,y=0,z=0,w=0
- Those 2 particles move apart in the 3D space such as:

Particle 1 is @ x1,y1,z1,w
and
Particle 2 is @ x2,y2,z2,w

Note that they are at the same w coordinate.

Can this be an explanation for the fact that the correlation is instantaneous?

I am not considering that this is a revolutionary thing. I am sure that a lot o people already thought about this, but I want to understand it better.

Comment: It's *vastly* more complicated than that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement

Comment: The fact that correlations are instantaneous doesn't need an explanation, because correlations are not causations.

Answer (score 1):

> *"What I know about quantum entanglement is almost nothing"*

Start by taking a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement

or, if you don't have some exposure to (formal) quantum mechanics, then here: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement